# Filter if_any everything behavior

Tags: r, dplyr

Good morning!

Ran into some odd behavior of the `filter(if_any(everything()))` call in dplyr.

```
# Reprex 

library(tidyverse)

## Does not work as expected -----------

iris %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), 
                ~ .x > 60))

## Works as expected ------------------

iris %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>% 
  filter(if_any(where(is.numeric), 
                ~ .x > 60))
```

The result I expect from both is a tibble of 0 x 0.  However, when one of the column types is a character, when filtering by everything, the returned tibble seems to be the entire dataframe.  Can someone explain why the result is not the same?

This behavior is particularly odd, since modifying the function slightly to `.x < 2` seems to produce the expected results.

```
# Also expected results --------------------
iris %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), 
                ~ .x < 2))
```

Anyway, looking forward to a response.  I really love the `if_any()` and `if_all()` implementations when filtering, and really want these functions to succeed.

Thank you for your time and consideration on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because :

```
as.character(unique(iris$Species)) > 60
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

whereas :

```
as.character(unique(iris$Species)) < 2
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Here as we are comparing numbers with strings it coerces 60 and 2 as string as well and then compares it the `Species`. Using `where(is.numeric)` is the correct way because it does not make sense to compare numbers with strings.

Comment: Weird, but that definitely explains the results.  Thank you for clarifying what was going on...I was baffled.